# Make Windows wake up from SSD before HDDs do

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, sleep

I have a PC running Windows 10 and all the programs off an NVME SSD, with two additional HDDs for storing media and other files. When the PC wakes up from sleep, I hear HDDs spinning up and then it takes some significant amount of time before UI is shown on screen. I suppose Windows decides it has to get HDDs fully ready before letting me interact with the system, so wakes up in this order:

1. Get SSD ready and start getting HDDs ready
2. Finish getting HDDs ready
3. Show UI on screen

Is there a way to make Windows wake up ASAP without waiting for HDDs? I don't mean to not wake HDDs at all or to not put them into sleep in the first place, just to not wait until they fully spin up. In other words, I want the PC to wake up in this order:

1. Get SSD ready and start getting HDDs ready
2. Show UI on screen
3. Finish getting HDDs ready

Would be nice to also have the same for system startup.

Comment: Try in CMD the command `chkntfs /x d: e:` for these two HDDs, shutdown and reboot to check.

Comment: *Is there a way to make Windows wake up ASAP without waiting for HDDs?* No.

Comment: @harrymc this is a plain bad suggestion...

Comment: @PierU: It should be undone if it doesn't help.

Comment: @harrymc beyond that, it has no chance to help. `chkntfs /x` will prevent Windows checking the filesystems at **boot** time (even if they need to, which is not a good idea), while the user here would like a faster wake up after **sleep** (so no boot involved).

Comment: Have you disabled search indexing on the drives?

Comment: @Mastaxx no, I didn't. One of them is a drive to store media, and the other has some documents, so I'd like to have search indexing enabled. Is it necessary to disable it, and will it really help?